How to run specific parameterized JUnit5 test 'instance' via maven?
Lets have JUnit5 test:
....
public class SomeClass {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource(...)
    void test(...) {}
}

we can run it via maven:
mvn -Dtest=SomeClass test

but how to run it, via maven, if I want to run only i-th 'instance' (or how it's called)? I.e. I don't want to run all tests for all parameters, just 1 test run for one specific parameter set.

I would suggest to run that via your IDE...

I know how to do that via ide, that's not the question. Why: ton of logs produced, which I need to automatically parse and analyze. From ide I can only put it into clipboard or reconfigure logger to put the logs into file, which I can process from CLI then. --> inconvenient, actually.

Instead of using Maven, you can use the JUnit Platform CLI or API. It has some options to select a specific elements of a parameterized test.
